# React event bubling / propagation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component like:

```
<div onClick={toggleHiden} className="faq-item-header">
 <h3>What is Bookmark?</h3>
 <img src={iconArrow} alt="arrow" />
</div>
```

[image]

This is the onclick function, I just want to toggle classlist.

```
const toggleHiden = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
    e.target.nextSibling.firstChild.classList.toggle("hidden");
  };
```

My plan is to run `toggleHiden` function on div click, but when my mouse click above `img` or `h3` the `e.target` is changing,
I try to add `stopPropagation` into the h3:

```
<h3 onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>What is Bookmark?</h3>
```

and now the h3 cannot be clicked.

What I want is whether I click on the `img` or `h3` it still count as click on the parent `div`

How I can overcome this?

Comment: You should either use ref or something else. e.target should be avoided in such case.
Or, You could do is. e.target.parent() if h3 or img is clicked.

Comment: @bnaysmhz why avoiding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this approach then you can do following:

```
if(e.target.tagName === "h3" || e.target.tagName === "img") {             
   e.target.parent.nextSibling.firstChild.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
else {
  e.target.nextSibling.firstChild.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.srcElement` instead of `event.target`, as `target` is the deepest element you clicked, it may be not the same element you bind the click event with, it can be one of it's children.

Or you can covert you click handler function to a `declaration function` and use `this` instead.